# Get page url and shorten link in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to get a particular page url and shorten the url automatically, and show it to the user. After writing the below codes, it's not shortening and no error was displayed.

Models.py

```
_char_map = string.ascii_letters+string.digits

def index_to_char(sequence):
     return "".join([_char_map[x] for x in sequence])

class Arts(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User)
     title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
     picture_1=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
     picture_2=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos", null=True,blank=True)
     picture_3=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos", null=True,blank=True)
     description=HTMLField(null=True,blank=True)
     slug=models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
     pub_date=models.DateTimeField()

     def __unicode__(self):
         return u'%s' %(self.title)

     def get_short_id(self):
          _id=self.id
           digits=[]
           while _id > 0:
              rem= _id % 62
              digits.append(rem)
              _id /=62
           digits.reverse()
          return index_to_char(digits)

     @staticmethod
     def decode_id(string):
        i=0
        for c in string:
            i=i*64+_char_map.index(c)
        return i

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if not self.id:
            self.slug=slugify(self.title)
         super(Arts,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Views.py

## The page of I want to shorten the links

```
  def artdetail(request,arts_id,slug):
      post=Arts.objects.get(id=arts_id,slug=slug)

      link_db=models.Arts()
      currentUrl = request.build_absolute_uri(link_db.get_short_id())
      return render_to_response('postdetail.html',{'post':post, ' Arts':Arts,'currentUrl':currentUrl},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
 {{currentUrl}}
```

Is this the best way to go about it? What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_db=models.Arts()` here you are referring to a new instace of the Art model; where you need to refer to the instance you have fetched, which is `post`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def artdetail(request,arts_id,slug):
      post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=arts_id,slug=slug)
      currentUrl = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_short_id())
      return render(request,
                    'postdetail.html',
                    {'post':post,'Arts':Arts,'currentUrl':currentUrl})
```

Comment: Thanks. After testing your codes, it didn't shorten the url correctly. The page url is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/artlyf/1/topman/ After shortening, it prints out this url on the template: http://127.0.0.1:8000/artlyf/1/topman/b   Any idea?

Comment: Well that's an entirely different question :)

Comment: This is my urls.py:url(r'^artlyf/(?P<arts_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\d\w]+)/$', 'artapp.views.artdetail', name='artdetail'),

Comment: To start off with, what is `index_to_char`?

Comment: I forgot to add this :_char_map = string.ascii_letters+string.digits

def index_to_char(sequence):
    return "".join([_char_map[x] for x in sequence])  its a function that converts the links.

Answer (score 1):

`link_db=models.Arts()` results in `link_db` being a new object, which doesn't have id assigned, maybe that's why it doesn't generate url.

I think instead `link_db.get_short_id()` you meant `post.get_short_id()`.

Comment: Thanks. After testing your codes, it didn't shorten the url correctly. The page url is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/artlyf/1/topman/ After shortening, it prints out this url on the template: http://127.0.0.1:8000/artlyf/1/topman/b   Any idea?